# Change color of slices of piechart in plotly.js using react-plotly.js

Tags: reactjs, plotly.js, plotly-react

```
import Plotly from "plotly.js";
import createPlotlyComponent from "react-plotly.js/factory";

export const Plot = createPlotlyComponent(Plotly);

export function PieChart() {
  return <Plot data={data} layout={layout} config={{ displaylogo: false }} useResizeHandler={true} style={{ width: '100%' }} />;
}
```

I want to change the color of Piechart slices, I referred to the documentation of plotly and added

```
marker: {
    color: 'rgba(255,153,51,0.6)',
    width: 1
}
```

too but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is array,

`maker.color` --> `maker.colors`

You can do this as below

```
marker: {
   colors: ['rgb(56, 75, 126)', 'rgb(18, 36, 37)', 'rgb(34, 53, 101)'],
   width: 1
}
```

Here is [DEMO](https://codepen.io/jornathan/pen/JjOOEPQ) for this,